# Runtime Exception while using the Settings in Android (I am following the udacity Android Developer course)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I am new to android and following the Udacity Android developer course to learn.
I am on chapter 3 where they teach about the adding the settings in your app. I have added the SettingActivity from android  studio. When I click on settings menu, my app crashes.
This is my pref_general.xml file

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference accepts EditText attributes. -->
<!-- NOTE: EditTextPreference's summary should be set to its value by the activity code. -->
<EditTextPreference
    android:key="@string/pref_location_key"
    android:defaultValue="@string/pref_location_default"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:title="@string/pref_location_label" />
```

I have made these changes in SettingActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setupActionBar();
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_general);
bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(findPreference(getString(R.string.pref_location_key)));}
```

I am getting following exception when I click the Setting menu

```
Process: com.example.android.sunshine.app, PID: 10131
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.sunshine.app/com.example.android.sunshine.app.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Modern two-pane PreferenceActivity requires use of a PreferenceFragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Modern two-pane PreferenceActivity requires use of a PreferenceFragment
 at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.requirePreferenceManager(PreferenceActivity.java:1441)
 at android.preference.PreferenceActivity.addPreferencesFromResource(PreferenceActivity.java:1511)
 at com.example.android.sunshine.app.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:124)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Any help? Sorry if its very naive thing

Answer (score 4):

I was able to solve this.
I was changing the OnCreate of my SettingActivity instead of changing my OnCreate of SettingFragment which is static private class of SettingActivity.

Comment: Cna you share some example for it?

Answer (score 0):

@mayank agrawal

He meant that the changes are to be done in class which extends PreferenceFragment. i.e you'll have to either extend PreferenceFragment.

Although the code is quite explanatory on the [Developers site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html), here I've taken some part of just to mention what he meant (by putting comments in the code).

```
public class PreferenceWithHeaders extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...           
    }
           //static class extending PreferenceFragment

    public static class Prefs1Fragment extends PreferenceFragment {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(getActivity(),
                    R.xml.advanced_preferences, false);

            // Here's where you've to load the preferences from an XML resource
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragmented_preferences);
        }
    }


    private void private void bindPreferenceSummaryToValue(Preference preference) {
        ...
    }
}
```

If your app supports API 10 or low then it's mandatory that you use Preference Activity. However you can also use that deprecated way on new API as well. Here's a [nice explanation in details](http://rominirani.com/android-preferences-tutorial/) for the beginners.

(I too am learning. So if anybody expert find any mistake then please let me know.)